# How to load two collections of related entities with a minimum number of sql queries?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the entities:

Bank:

```java
public class Bank {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "bank_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "bank_name")
    private String bankName;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "bank", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<CreditDetails> creditDetails = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "bank", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Client:

```java
public class Client {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "client_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "client_name")
    private String clientName;

    @Column(name = "client_surname")
    private String clientSurName;

    @Column(name = "client_full_name")
    private String clientFullName;

    @Column(name = "telephone_number")
    private Long telephoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "passport_number")
    private Long passportNumber;

    @ManyToOne(
            cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "bank_id")
    private Bank bank;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "client")
    private List<CreditOffer> creditOffers = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Credit Details:

```java
public class CreditDetails {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "credit_details_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "credit_limit")
    private BigDecimal creditLimit;

    @Column(name = "credit_percent")
    private BigDecimal creditPercent;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Bank.class, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bank_id")
    private Bank bank;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "creditDetails")
    List<CreditOffer> creditOffers = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

My task is to load Clients and Credit Details with the least number of requests using Spring Data.

I tried to solve this problem using graphs, I added the following construction above the bank entity:

```java
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "BankWithClientsAndDetails", attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "creditDetails"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "clients",subgraph = "ClientWithBank")
})
```

However, when calling the method, I received a `MultiBagFetchException`, googled that this occurs due to the fact that a Cartesian product is obtained in the request.

Next, I tried to solve the problem by writing a SQL query manually, I made a test method of the following form:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM banks \n" +
            "JOIN clients ON clients.bank_id = banks.bank_id  \n" +
            "JOIN credit_details ON credit_details.bank_id = banks.bank_id \n" +
            "WHERE banks.bank_id = :id",nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<Bank> findBankWithSubEntitiesById(@Param(value = "id") UUID id);
```

The number of requests has remained huge, since related entities have more related entities, and those have one more. At this stage, my hands dropped and I came to you to ask for help. How would you solve this situation? Do I really have to put up with N + 1 in my case. I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using just JOIN in your query merely narrows the results, eg - it won't loads banks without any clients and credit details.

You can tell hibernate to load each of these associations eagerly using JOIN FETCH jpql keyword.

```
SELECT bank
FROM Bank bank
JOIN FETCH bank.clients
JOIN FETCH bank.creditDetails
WHERE bank.id = :bankId
```

Keep in mind that this is a jpql query, so you have to remove `nativeQuery = true` parameter. Also, note that by default, join is inner and not outer - meaning that this query also won't return a bank without clients or credit details. You can change that by using `LEFT JOIN FETCH`, but that will reduce performance, so choose whatever strategy suits best your use-case.

[Further reading](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-the-importance-of-fetch-strategy/)